# いいねボタンを押すと投稿詳細ページに飛んでしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

#### 前提・実現したいこと

前提：いいねボタンは投稿一覧ページに実装済み、投稿詳細ページにもいいね機能を実装しております。
実現したいこと：投稿一覧ページのいいねボタンを押すと、投稿一覧ページにリダイレクトしてカウントをさせたい。＋投稿詳細ページのいいね機能は変わらず実装したい。

投稿一覧ページ：post_images/index.html.erb

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

現状：いいねボタンを押すと投稿詳細ページに飛んでしまう、カウントはする。

#### 該当のソースコード

post_images/index.html.erb

```
<section class="sct-color-1 slice">
  <div class="container-fluid masonry-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="masonry-wrapper-cols">
          <div class="masonry-gutter"></div>
            <% @post_images.each do |post_image| %>
            <div class="masonry-block">
              <div class="block block-image v1">
                <div class="block-image">
                  <div class="view view-first">
                  <%= link_to post_image_path(post_image.id) do %>
                    <%= attachment_image_tag post_image, :image %>
                  <% end %>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="block-content">
                  <%= attachment_image_tag post_image.user, :profile_image, size: "100x100", fallback: "no_image.jpg", class:"img-circle pull-left profile-thumb" %>
                  <h3 class="block-title">
                      <%= post_image.image_name %>
                  </h3>
                  <ul class="inline-meta">
                    <li>By
                      <%= post_image.user.name %>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <%= link_to "#{post_image.post_comments.count} コメント", post_image_path(post_image.id) %>
                    </li>


                    <% if post_image.favorited_by?(current_user) %>
                      <li>
                        <%= link_to post_image_favorites_path(post_image), method: :delete do %>
                          <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="color: orange; font-size: 15px;"></i>
                          <%= post_image.favorites.count %> ファイト
                        <% end %>
                      </li>
                    <% else %>
                      <li>
                        <%= link_to post_image_favorites_path(post_image), method: :post do %>
                          <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 15px;"></i>
                          <%= post_image.favorites.count %> ファイト
                        <% end %>
                      </li>
                    <% end %>


                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <% end %>
            <%= paginate @post_images, class: "paginate" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

favorites_controller.rb

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        post_image = PostImage.find(params[:post_image_id])
        favorite = current_user.favorites.new(post_image_id: post_image.id)
        favorite.save
        redirect_to post_image_path(post_image)
    end

    def destroy
        post_image = PostImage.find(params[:post_image_id])
        favorite = current_user.favorites.find_by(post_image_id: post_image.id)
        favorite.destroy
        redirect_to post_image_path(post_image)
    end
end
```

post_image.rb

```
class PostImage < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    attachment :image
    has_many :post_comments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
    validates :image_name, presence: true
    validates :image, presence: true
    def favorited_by?(user)
        favorites.where(user_id: user.id).exists?
    end
end
```

post_images/show.html.erb

```
<section class="sct-color-1 slice">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 post_images_container">
        <div class="post-item">

        <div class="post-meta-top">
          <div class="post-image">
            <%= attachment_image_tag @post_image, :image %>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="post-content">
              <h2 class="post-title"><%= @post_image.image_name %></h2>
              <ul class="meta-info-cells v4 float-wrapper">
                <li>
                   <i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size: 15px;"></i>
                   <%= link_to @post_image.user.name, user_path(@post_image.user.id) %>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar" style="font-size: 15px;"></i><%= @post_image.created_at.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') %>
                </li>
                <% if @post_image.favorited_by?(current_user) %>
                  <li>
                    <%= link_to post_image_favorites_path(@post_image), method: :delete do %>
                      <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="color: orange; font-size: 15px;"></i>
                      <%= @post_image.favorites.count %> ファイト
                    <% end %>
                  </li>
                <% else %>
                  <li>
                    <%= link_to post_image_favorites_path(@post_image), method: :post do %>
                      <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 15px;"></i>
                      <%= @post_image.favorites.count %> ファイト
                    <% end %>
                  </li>
                <% end %>
                <li>
                  <i class="fa fa-comment" style="font-size: 15px;"></i>
                  <a href="#comments"><%= @post_image.post_comments.count %></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                 <% if @post_image.user == current_user %>
                  <%= link_to "削除", post_image_path(@post_image), method: :delete %>
                 <% end %>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="post-content-inner mt-20">
                  <p><%= @post_image.caption %></p>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="comment-list bt style-2" id="comments">
            <div class="float-wrapper">
              <h2 class="comment-count"><%= @post_image.post_comments.count %>件のコメント</h2>
            </div>
            <ol>
              <% @post_image.post_comments.each do |post_comment| %>
                <li class="comment">
                    <div class="comment-body bb">
                        <div class="comment-avatar">
                            <div class="avatar">
                                <%= attachment_image_tag psot_comment.user, :profile_image, 60, 60, fallback: "no_image.jpg" %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment-text">
                            <div class="comment-author clearfix">
                                <a href="#" class="link-author"><%= post_comment.user.name %></a>
                                <span class="comment-meta">
                                  <span class="comment-date"><%= post_comment.created_at.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') %></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-entry"><%= post_comment.comment %></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
              <% end %>
            </ol>
          </div>
          <hr>

          <!-- Add comment section -->
          <div class="section-title-wrapper style-1 v1 mt-30" id="divAddComment">
            <h3 class="section-title left">
              <span>コメント</span>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <%= form_for [@post_image, @post_comment] do |f| %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <%= f.text_area :comment, rows:'5', class: "form-control",placeholder: "コメントをここに" %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <%= f.submit "送信する", class: "btn btn-lg btn-base-1 mt-20 pull-right" %>
          <% end %>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

#### 試したこと

link_toのパスをpost_images_path(投稿一覧ページ)に変えたところrouting_errorになった

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Rails 5.2.4.1
ruby 2.5.7p206 (2019-10-01 revision 67816) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Comment: まずは、`FavoritesController`の`create`メソッド内の`redirect_to post_image_path(post_image)`を、`redirect_to post_images_path`にして、動作を確認するのがいいと思います。状況から察するに、`FavoritesController`の`create`が呼ばれるところまではうまく動いており、最後の`redirect_to post_image_path(post_image)`で、`PostImagesController`の`show`にいいねをした`post_image`のIDが渡されるようにリダイレクトされるため、投稿詳細ページが表示されていると思われます。うまく動きましたら、同様に`FavoritesController`の`delete`メソッドの最後も`redirect_to post_images_path`に変更しないと、いいねを外した時に投稿詳細ページが表示されてしまうと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Railsガイド見てみました。
https://railsguides.jp/routing.html

[image]

---

`post_image_path(post_image.id)` って書き方だと、
「articles#show」のアクションが呼ばれる気がします。
「articles#create」を呼ぶためには、`post_images_path` って書き方にする必要があるかもしれません。

ただ、`link_to` だとGETでrequestされる可能性があるので、
「articles#create」を呼ぶためにはPOSTでrequestする必要があるかと思われます。
なので、

```rb
<%= link_to post_images_path, method: :post do %>
    <%= attachment_image_tag post_image, :image %>
<% end %>
```

とかって書いたりすれば出来たりしませんか？

---

あと、controllerの`#create` の最後の部分、
`redirect_to post_images_path` にしないと一覧ページに戻らないかと思います。

Comment: 指摘のviewの`link_to`の部分は、イメージにリンクをつけ、クリックすることで詳細ページを表示するためのものと思われるため、関係ないと思われます。また、いいねの部分は`<% if post_image.favorited_by?(current_user) %>`内の`<%= link_to post_image_favorites_path(post_image), method: :post do %>`と思われ、こちらは指摘のようにmethodオプションが指定されているので、ここは問題ないと思われます。なお、最後の`redirect_to`の部分は、指摘の通りと思われます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。言葉足らずで申し訳ありません。favorites_controller.rbの```redirect_to post_image_path(post_image)```は投稿詳細ページにもいいね機能を実装しているため記載しているつもりです。投稿詳細ページに実装したいいね機能を投稿一覧ページにも同様に実装し、投稿一覧ページのいいねを押した際には詳細ページに飛ぶのではなく、投稿一覧ページにとどめたいという考えがあります。

Comment: きちんとコード読んでなくてすみません！！した後のページ移動したくないのであれば、一覧ページで使うためのactionひとつ作った方がいいかもしれません。遷移前のaction取得して遷移先条件分岐させる方法もあるみたいですが、特殊なやり方な気がしますね。